# PushWoosh - add custom broadcast receiver

Tags: android, pushwoosh

What I want to achieve: upon receiving PushWoosh notification, check the payload and direct user to specific activity accordingly.

I'm following an example in [PushWoosh FAQ section](http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/android-faq) regarding

> Using Custom Push Broadcast Receiver in Android

However, I'm unable to receive any push inside my custom push..

Here's the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".receivers.PWBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="${applicationId}.com.arellomobile.android.push.REGISTER_BROAD_CAST_ACTION"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.PushGCMIntentService" />
```

This is my custom broadcast receiver:

```
public class PWBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "PWBroadcastReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent == null)
            return;

        // Let Pushwoosh SDK to pre-handling push (Pushwoosh track stats, opens rich pages, etc.).
        // It will return Bundle with a push notification data
        Bundle pushBundle = PushManager.preHandlePush(context, intent);
        if (pushBundle == null)
            return;

        // Get push bundle as JSON object
        JSONObject dataObject = PushManager.bundleToJSON(pushBundle);

        // Get default launcher intent for clarity
        Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
        launchIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");

        launchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);

        // Put push notifications payload in Intent
        launchIntent.putExtras(pushBundle);
        launchIntent.putExtra(PushManager.PUSH_RECEIVE_EVENT, dataObject.toString());

        // Start activity!
        context.startActivity(launchIntent);

        // Let Pushwoosh SDK post-handle push (track stats, etc.)
        PushManager.postHandlePush(context, intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remote intent filter from PWBroadcastReceiver, you don't need it.
2. I don't see any meta tags in your AndroidManifest.xml

You need to add receiver name to meta-data tag to AndroidManifest.xml, otherwise SDK doesn't know where to route push notification.

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.PWBroadcastReceiver" />
<meta-data android:name="PW_NOTIFICATION_RECEIVER" android:value=".receivers.PWBroadcastReceiver"/>
```

> *UPDATE*:
>   Note that the `PW_NOTIFICATION_RECEIVER` expect `package + [path to your notification receiver class]`.. If you use an application_id (com.myapp.staging) different from original package name (com.myapp), this may cause problem.. and the fix is to use the original package instead of application id